# Offline channel reports not working

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

In the `Experience Analytics`, none of the "Offline Channel" reports are showing any graphs for our site. All the reports show - "No data to display".

Aquisition - Channels - Offline - Offline
Aquisition - Channels - Offline - Offline channels by visits and value per visit
Aquisition - Channels - Offline - Offline channels by value
Aquisition - Channels - Offline - Offline channels by conversion
Aquisition - Channels - Offline - All channels groups

Our site is *www.example.com*. If there is another site *abc.com* or a *facebook page* which has a link to our site, then these two sites are offline channels. Is my understanding correct.

Is there any configuration to be done like a goal creation, for these graphs to show up, or just having a link on another site is enough for the analytics to work.

Using Sitecore 8.2 update 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Offline channels** are, by definition, not online. Some examples of this would be direct mail campaigns with a QR code, telemarketing, a physical event like a trade show, etc.

See Sitecore's documentation for more information:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/marketing_operations/channels/the_offline_channel_groups_and_their_channels

In order to get traffic to appear in your Offline Channel reports, you will need to associate your content with some of these offline channels.